# How to handle the event from dynamically generated button c#

Tags: c#, xamarin

First of all I am new at IT developing, and I just learning...
I have a RunTime button and I want to handle the event for each button, how can I do it?
This is the code that I have;

```
  public partial class Dashboard : ContentPage
{

    private IList<Condominium> output;


    public Dashboard(IList<Condominium> output)
    {

        var Buttonadd = new Style(typeof(Button))
        {
            Setters = {
                        new Setter {Property = Button.TextColorProperty, Value = Constants.MainTextColor},
                        new Setter {Property = Button.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Constants.BackgroundColor},
                        new Setter {Property = Button.HorizontalOptionsProperty, Value = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand},
                        new Setter {Property = Button.VerticalOptionsProperty, Value = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand},
                        new Setter {Property = Button.TextProperty, Value = TextAlignment.End},
                        new Setter {Property = Button.WidthRequestProperty, Value = 200},
                        new Setter {Property = Button.HeightRequestProperty, Value = 200},
                       }
        };



        StackLayout parent = new StackLayout();

        foreach (var cond in output)
        {
            Button add = new Button
            {
                Style = Buttonadd,
                Text = cond.Name,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, -10, 0, -10),

            };



            parent.Children.Add(add);


        }


        Content = new ScrollView
        {
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 10),
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            Content = parent,
        };


        this.output = output;


        InitializeComponent();
    }



}
}
```

Comment: Try `add.Click += YourClickHandler;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the click event.

You can read up on the button event [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.Button.Clicked/)

Also see [EventHandler Delegate](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.EventHandler/) for a better understanding how the `Clicked` event handler works.

```
Button btnToAdd = new Button
{
    Style = Buttonadd,
    Text = cond.Name,
    Margin = new Thickness(0, -10, 0, -10),

};

btnToAdd.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;

parent.Children.Add(add);
```

and then add your event handler:

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //add your code here
}
```